# the WordPress registration form with unique token

Tags: wordpress, registration

I have a meetup theme in my WordPress-site with a contact form. I would like to have a unique token for users. After registration by the user, the token will be sent to their emails and I will see this token in my registration list. How can I do something like this?

In my 'Email Template When register successfully' block I've got this code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>New Free Register<`enter code here`/h2>
        <h4>Booking information</h4>
        <strong>Customer ID</strong>[customerid]
        <br/>
        <strong>Buyer Information</strong>
        <br/>[userinfo]
        <?php
            function generateKey() {
                $keyLength=8;
                $str="1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm#!?()";
                $randStr= substr(str_shuffle($str),0,$keyLength);
                return $randStr;
            }
            echo "Token:";
            echo generateKey();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download this package https://github.com/nats-io/node-nuid and call nuid.next() after registration.

Comment: Where should I put this package?